# Using SlideView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want to use slideview between view controllers. I find these source

[ECSliding view controller](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController)

But in this code, it use with storyboard. I don't want to use storyboard, i want to use on nib file.
How can I do this ?

Comment: What's wrong with storyboards?

Comment: Don't use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions not about the IDE. Thanks!

Comment: Because i don't use storyboard in my project. I have need code for nib file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://code4app.com/ios/Side-bar-demo/50c83b396803fa2d4d000001 try this. But it's Chinese, you can translate it, code can be downloaded via the big button right side[image].

It uses the xib, very simple and useful. Hopefully it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
     UIViewController *topController = [[TopController alloc] initWithNibName:<#(NSString *)#> bundle:<#(NSBundle *)#>];           
     UINavigationController *topViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:topController];

     ECSlidingViewController *slidingController = [[ECSlidingViewController alloc] initWithTopViewController:topViewController];

     slidingController.underLeftViewController = [[SideMenuController alloc]   initWithNibName:<#(NSString *)#> bundle:<#(NSBundle *)#>];
     [window setRootViewController:slidingController];
     [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

If you need reference for the set up of top view controller and sidemenu controller, you can refer to the example project - TransitionFun. Top view and under view controller could be any UIViewController.